# how to remove render blocking style error (lighthouse plugin )

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, lighthouse

I am using `external stylesheet` in my application. When I check my application performance it show me `remove render blocking style link`. So I used link tag like this:

```
<link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/base.css" key="" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://www.****.com/asset/web/css/styles.css" key="" rel="stylesheet" />
```

So to remove this error `remove render blocking style link`, I tried to `preload` my link like this:

```
<link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/base.css"
  key=""
  as="style"
  onLoad="this.rel = 'stylesheet'"
  rel="preload"
/>
<link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/styles.css"
  key=""
  as="style"
  onLoad="this.rel = 'stylesheet'"
  rel="preload"
/>
```

Now when I run my application my page become blank. When I open inspect element without doing anything it show all contend with css applied. What I am doing wrong? Why does it show a blank page?

Comment: The content is blank or there are no styles applied? If it is blank, this is likely that you have a "loading screen" / spinner, the JS that removes that is not getting triggered for some reason. I am guessing you have no console errors? Also, not that it *should* make a difference but it should be `onload` no `onLoad`, always lower case, it should work anyway. If you want to share the URL or create a fiddle that replicates the problem we can help further but your HTML looks ok. Just to check you do know you need to inline critical styles if you do this to avoid layout shifts etc?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
      <link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/base.css" 
              key=""
              as="style"
              rel="preload"
        />
        <link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/styles.css"
              key=""
              as="style"
              rel="preload"
        />
        <link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/base.css"
              key=""
              rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link href="https://www.*****.com/asset/web/css/styles.css"
              key=""
              rel="stylesheet"
        />
```